# Why Dart Null Safety principles only apply on the statically typed variables not type inferred?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am studying dart null safety concepts and I have found that all principles apply only on the statically typed variables, int a for example, not on the type inferred the ones declare with 'var' keyword. Why do null safety rules apply to one of the variables created with the 'var' keyword? I just want to the reason why dart doesn't deal with type inferred variables. Thank you

Comment: When using `var`, the type is automatically determined based on the initial value of the variable. So if the initial value is from a nullable type, the `var` variable is going to be a nullable variable.

Comment: @Muhammad Afzal Can you provide specific examples of what you're asking about?  Your question is unclear since null safety concepts do apply to inferred types, and inferred types are static (known at compile-time).

Comment: @jamesdlin I just want to know why we can't write `var? myVariable`? And can we apply null safety principles on `var a` variable `a`?

Comment: Var  basically means "I don't care to notate the type for this variable." Dart will replace the var keyword with the initializer type, or leave it dynamic by default if there is no initializer. Hence, if you don´t care about the type you also do not care about null safety principles or in other words, whether it is nullable or non-nullable.

Comment: thank you @JahnE. for the nice explanation. Now I got the point, we all know that we can assign a null value to var, it means `var` is ready to accept null value then why we will care about the null why will we apply null safety principles on it? because null safety always tries to protect us from the situations that get null values, it doesn't make sense to explain to a foolish person if he himself wants to be a foolish person. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am studying dart null safety concepts and I have found that all principles apply only on the statically typed variables, `int a` for example, not on the type inferred the ones declare with `var` keyword.

Null-safety concepts *do* apply to inferred types:

```dart
int? f() => 42;

var x = f(); // The static type of `x` is `int?`.
```

It's true that you currently can't write `var?` to explicitly declare that a variable should use a nullable version of the inferred type.  It's something that the Dart language team has considered and is still open to adding.  See:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1238
- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1030

where [Lasse Nielsen explains](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1030#issuecomment-643955370):

> The reason `var?` is not supported is, roughly, that `?` is something you add on types, and `var` is not a *type*. It's a declaration marker that occurs instead of a type, like `final` - except that `final` can also be combined with at type, while `var` can't.

The cases where you'd want to use `var?` are if you have a non-`null` initial value *and* want to set that variable to `null` later.  In practice, I'd expect those situations aren't very common, so it's not a prioritized feature.  For such cases, you should declare the variable with an explicit type (e.g. `int? x = 42;`).

If you *really* want to avoid typing the typename, you could apply [Erik Ernst's suggestion](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1030#issuecomment-643950746).  For example: `var x = null ?? 42;`.

Alternatively you could make a helper function:

```dart
T? makeNullable<T>(T object) => object;

var x = makeNullable(42);
```

But I personally think those approaches are overkill and are less readable.

Comment: @jamesdin thank you for the reference links, I agree the situations aren't common where we have to assign a null to var and in case it happens then we can use `int?` method.

Answer (score 2):

**Before I get to your question, here is the fundamental priniciple:**

```
String? nullableString; // is currently null

String nonNullableString; // needs to be initialized, because it can´t be null

var myVariable; // will always be dynamic (see comment from jamesdlin)

var myVariable = "Hello World"; 
// var is non-nullable, since the non-nullable type String can be inferred
```

In contrast to `type? variable; // variable can be null.`

**Why Dart Null Safety principles only apply on the statically typed variables not type inferred?**

The reason for it is quite simple, Dart will infer whether var is a nullable or non-nullable type based on the initial value, so there is no reason for you to write something like "var?". Dart is basically dealing with type inferred variables behind the scenes so to say.

Comment: `var myVariable;` will not infer any type.  Without an explicit type or an initial value to infer the type from, `myVariable` will be of type `dynamic`.

Comment: Your correct, sorry for that uppsi - I edited my answer

Comment: Not quite. `var myVariable;` will always make `myVariable` `dynamic`, even if it's given a value later.  That is, `var myVariable; myVariable = 'Hello world';` will not change the static type of `myVariable` to `String`; it will still be `dynamic`.

Comment: Strange, I did not know that. But why is the static analyzer in VS Code then able to infer it as a String in your example?

Comment: I do not observe that with either VS Code or DartPad.  In VS Code, hovering over `myVariable` for either statement shows a tooltip indicating that it is `dynamic`.

Comment: You´re right. I thought since it does not show a warning / an error when using Text(myVariable) it infers it as a String, but whilst hovering it indeed is dynamic. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JahnE. thank you for the answer but still I am confused why dart null safety principles do not apply to variables created with `var` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Dart provides us various options to deal with nullable and non-nullable variables. Dart asks us to use type annotation when you are obvious and we can use null safety rules to make our code safe from null and we can use `var` keyword when there are chances of null and it does not make sense to protect `var` from null as it's allowing null to put into it.